# Use asterisk in count with table alias T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do we use an aggregate function, like `COUNT`, with `*` in conjunction with an alias? `COUNT` allows table alias to be used with column names but not `*`.

This works:

```
select e.*, COUNT(e.MGR)
from EMP as e 
left outer join EMP as e1 on e.EMPNO = e1.EMPNO
group by e.[EMPNO], e.[ENAME], e.[JOB], e.[MGR], e.[HIREDATE], e.[SAL], e.[COMM], e.[DEPTNO]
```

but this does not:

```
select e.*, COUNT(e.*)
from EMP as e 
left outer join EMP as e1 on e.EMPNO = e1.EMPNO
group by e.[EMPNO], e.[ENAME], e.[JOB], e.[MGR], e.[HIREDATE], e.[SAL], e.[COMM], e.[DEPTNO]
```

This example being used above is a made up one to demonstrate the case. There is no NOT-NULL column in either table. So how do we count the number of rows in left hand side table of a left outer join

Comment: A row can't have a `NULL` or non-`NULL` value. When using `*`with `COUNT` it simply counts the number of rows in the entire dataset, but you can't reference a subset of the dataset like that in a function.

Comment: What are you actually trying to count?

Comment: @bendataclear i have edited the question to clarify that i am trying to count rows in the left hand side table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no NOT-NULL column in either table. So how do we count the
>   number of rows in left hand side table of a left outer join

This should not happen, because every table should have a primary key, guaranteeing at least one NOT NULL column.

Without such a column you can create one at runtime by joining onto a derived table that projects a NOT NULL constant and counting that column.

```
select e.*, COUNT(e.Flag)
from (SELECT, *, 1 AS Flag FROM EMP) as e 
left outer join EMP as e1 on e.EMPNO = e1.EMPNO
group by ...
```

Comment: This is not exactly what i was looking for but as it is a workaround, i will mark it is as the answer

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

Use either the primary key or one of the columns used in the `JOIN`:

```
select e.*, COUNT(e1.EMPNO)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could also count a non-`NULL`able column in the joined table (the PK will already be that, so is generally the "best" candidate though).

Comment: Yes, I could use primary key/non-null column. But i should have clarified that in this case there is no NOT-NULL columns in either table. I will update the question and also change the join to left outer and use COUNT on the left hand side table.